# ng-class not evaluating to true

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have some html with which I'm trying to use ng-class. If I just hardcode in "true", my CSS for the class is applied as expected. But, as soon as I replace the true with an expression (shown below), it seems my class isn't being applied. Here is the line of HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems"><span ng-class="{active: $index==activeIndex}" class="underline"><a ng-href={{menuItem.itemLink}}>{{menuItem.itemName}}</a></span></li>
```

And the code from the controller:

```
      $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(index){
        $scope.activeIndex = index;
        console.log("Set Active Index");
      });
```

Comment: `$index` is the iterator offset given to each template instance's scope by the `ng-repeat` directive. The expression looks fine. However what are you trying to achieve by binding to the `$routeChangeSuccess` event? What you are returning as `index` here is the next route.

Comment: Thanks very much. I couldn't figure out why index was not a numeric when looking in the console in Chrome. This is due to my limited JS knowledge, as I am still learning coming from other software backgrounds. Now that you mention this, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the index param of the '$routeChangeSuccess' event callback is not a number as you expected.
If you want to change your actived list when route change. you can pass $location service to $scope.

here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/yRHwm/4/

HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems">
            <!-- use $location.path() to detect current path -->
            <span ng-class="{'active': menuItem.itemLink==$location.path()}" class="underline">
                <a ng-href="#{{menuItem.itemLink}}">{{menuItem.itemName}}</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Javscript Code:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/1', {controller:'firstController'})
    .when('/2', {controller:'secondController'})
})
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.menuItems = [
        {itemLink: '/1', itemName: 'Link1'},
        {itemLink: '/2', itemName: 'Link2'}
    ];

    // pass $location service to scope, then you can use $location.path() to detect current path
    $scope.$location = $location;

    // this is no longer used. just to show index is not a number
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(index){
        $scope.activeIndex = index;
        // you can see in the console which index is not a number.
        console.log("Set Active Index", index);
    });
})
.controller('firstController', function($scope){
    console.log('first');
})
.controller('secondController', function($scope){
   console.log('second');
});
```